# DLL load failed : in installing opencv2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

```
Python 3.5.3 (v3.5.3:1880cb95a742, Jan 16 2017, 15:51:26) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I am trying to install open cv on python but this message shows up.
should I download opencv of 32 bit is this the case?

Comment: If your machine is 64 bit it should support 32 bit as well but for that both python executable and DLL must be of same bit

Comment: yes but Why this error is coming I installed opencv in drive C and pasted cv2.pyd in python libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `pip install opencv-python` it worked for me https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python

Comment: Please mark your answer if it worked correctly this would help others facing similar issue to find your answer quickly

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with incompatible lib.numpy is (mostly) compatible with 32bit.
So install

1. Python (32bit)
2. Numpy
3. OpenCV(32 bit)

Python 2.7 is only compatible with OpenCV2

Doesn't matter if you have a 64bit machine, 32-bit software can be run on a 64-bit Operating System.